# Не работает pyttsx3 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Есть код:

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Модули pywin32, pypiwin32 и pyttsx3 установлены.
Запускаю, ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Ilona\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 30, in buildDriver
    return SAPI5Driver(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.setProperty('voice', self.getProperty('voice'))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 100, in setProperty
    token = self._tokenFromId(value)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 80, in _tokenFromId
    tokens = self._tts.GetVoices()
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147200967, None, (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

Что делать?
Версия Python 3.6.0